# Why does VSC save my Haskell files as a .hsig and can i change the deafault to .hs?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, haskell, visual-studio-code

We are forced to program some Haskell in college and VSC saves my Haskell code as a .hsig file.

The GHCI can't compile .hsig file, so I have to change it by hand every time.

Because I am lazy I would love to know if I could just change the default extention.

Comment: This was a bug in the VSCode Haskell support. It has since been fixed: https://github.com/JustusAdam/language-haskell/issues/197

Comment: FYI, telling people who follow the [tag:haskell] tag that you're "forced" to use what's likely one of their favorite languages is not a highly effective way to get them to want to help you.